# OData Client Setup with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, odata, .net-7.0

I built an OData endpoint and it's working great, I can use Postman to query. I even built a console app and used connected services to create a proxy for my OData endpoints.

```
var data = new MyContainer(new Uri("https://LocalHost:43200/odata"));
var customers = data.Customers.Execute(); 
   
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(customer.AccountName);
}
```

The above code works. Now I'm creating an API that will talk to my OData endpoint. I want to add the container instantiation to the program.cs using dependency injection (DI) like you would a DbContext:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
 options.UseSqlServer("Server=MyDataServer;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");
});
```

I can't seem to find something to do this for OData with a URI. I've tried several OData Nuget packages and can't find anything with `.AddOData` to the `builder.Services`. I've searched for this and can only find code like my first example or mostly how to build an OData API using DI.

This seems like it should be simple, maybe I can do it with an `AddScoped`, just not sure how to pass in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that appears to work. I'm still having trouble with my Post commands but doubt it's related to this DI code. The Get's are working.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyContainer>(x =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyContainer>(x, new Uri("https://localhost:44312/odata")));
```

This allows me to use DI with a constructor. I feel like there might still be an AddOData method out there somewhere but this will have to do.